# Как пересобрать php?

Tags: php, postgresql

я установил phppgadmin. При заходе на страницу просит пересобрать php

> Ваша инсталяция PHP не поддерживает PostgreSQL. Вам необходимо
> пересобрать PHP, используя параметр --with-pgsql для configure.

Как пересобрать php с нужным параметром(выше) на убунту?

Answer (score 0):

Можно docker поставить и hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/phppgadmin – Sergei Kirjanov 1 час назад

(именно phppgadmin я не ставил, это общий ответ)

Я обычно не-GUI программы в docker/docker-compose ставлю: нет проблем с версиями, мусор потом легче убирать из системы.

И еще, контейнеры эфeмерны. Если программа пишет не временные, a ценные данные -- нужно описать это, как `volume`.

Comment: Я попробовал со своей версией(7.4). Пишет что уже установленно

Comment: Или что-то из этого: `apt search php | grep pgsql`

Comment: Вывело мол установленно

Comment: можно docker поставить и https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/phppgadmin

Comment: если что, именно phppgadmin я не ставил, это общие мысли

Comment: Хорошо, пока подожду другие ответы, и если что, попробую ваш

Answer (score 0):

Для активации в Ubuntu модуля PHP для PostgreSQL установите через apt пакет [php-pgsql](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/php-pgsql). Кроме того, напоминаю, в репозиториях Ubuntu уже есть преднастроеный вариант [phppgadmin](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/phppgadmin), кторый также возможно установить через apt.

Comment: `php-pgsql` подходит под `apt search php | grep pgsql` из комментариев

Comment: Именно вторым способом и было всё установленно, но ошибка существует, также модуль PHP поставлен

Comment: Возможно, какой-то дефект в пакете phppgadmin. Но мне не удалось его воспроизвести. Прямо только что установил этот пакет вместе с postgresql в чистую виртуалку с GNU/Linux Ubuntu MATE 20.04, создал себе пользователя в постгресе и успешно смог воспользоваться http://localhost/phppgadmin/

Comment: В общем, чтобы воспользоваться phpPgAdmin, никакой PHP пересобирать не нужно. Расскажите, пожалуйста, какие версии ПО у вас установлены, относящиеся к этому сценарию. Установлены ли рекомендуемые пакеты?